# PHP:: Best way to detect if session start

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I was wondering if this if statement :

```
if(session_id()===""){}
```

is equivalent to this if statement :

```
if(!session_id()){}
```

Both works for me!

but I like the sorter line so I was just wondering if it's 100% equivalent and I can rely on that to detect if session is started.

Comment: The second one will not work, if you session id *would* be like 0. I would stick with the first one

Comment: Thanks ! I would stick with the first one :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those statements are not fully equivalent.

`if(!session_id()){}` means `if(session_id() != TRUE){}` so the `session_id()` function could return `0`, `FALSE`, `''`, `NULL`.

and `if(session_id()===""){}` is checking if `session_id()` is returning empty STRING, so the only option, for which the `if` statement will return TRUE, is `''`.

From PHP Manual about [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php):

> session_id() returns the session id for the current session or the
>   empty string ("") if there is no current session (no current session
>   id exists).

So, the preferable is to use the 1st way.